# website navigation with multiple locations on one domain

Tags: html, navigation, site-structure

I am now managing the Webpage for the Piano Institute Switzerland.
The institute now has multiple locations and a webpage for each location.

Due to the overhead managing all webpages, we thought about merging to one webpage with a structure like:

```
klavierinstitut.ch/basel
klavierinstitut.ch/uster
klavierinstitut.ch/zurich
```

each page will have 2 own pages such as `landing page` and `location`
all other information/pages will be shared. Eg prices, contact, enrollment, ...
The question is now: how would the navigation work?
So if I go from `.ch/basel/index.html` -> `.ch/prices.html` how do I get back to the `.ch/basel/index.html` through the navigation?

Comment: Wouldn't your navigation have links to base1, uster, and zurich?

Comment: so you would put a link to each page in the navigation. That might be a little bloated.

Comment: To me, this is opinion based. You can do it in do many ways. Dropdown and button, or tabs, or next/prev buttons or a button for each location etc. Just look around at other sites.

Comment: @julianbechtold what do you mean with `a little bloated`? If you have no navigation link to a page, how user will reach it? Another question is: do you really need dedicated pages for each location? What content do you have on pages like `basel/index.html?`

Comment: Content is mostly the same. 
Whats different is the location page, as well as some minor wordings on index.html.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think with dedicated location pages you will force Google to rank your site for certain locations.

Because of this I would recommend to merge all locations on the same URL (/locations/ or, even better, on the start page), i.e. each location content in the own content accordeon part.

On this way you will have pages like: /prices, /contact, /enrollment - thats all.